# For simple weight constraints: Add constraint directly or use parameterization without constraint

Tags: constrained-optimization, numerical-algorithms

I am wondering if it makes sense to parameterize simple weight inequalities, for example if the weights should be $w\geq 0$, one cound train $\exp w$ over the unconstrained set instead. Also, if $\sum w_i=1$ one could parameterize $\frac{e^{w_i}}{\sum e^{w_i}}$ and optimize over the unconstrained set.

While the solutions should be the same, I wonder if it makes numerically a difference, and what way is the right one. I guess the values of $\exp$ might explode and it becomes numerically unstable.

Question: should I use something like tf.keras.constraints.NonNeg() or should I replace each weight $w$, on which I want to apply the constraint with $\exp w$ ("reparameterization") (since exp>0)or is there no general rule?

Comment: Can you please reformulate the title in the form of a **specific** question, so that it's clear what you're really asking here? I don't see any question in your post!

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. I want to use a non-negative weight constraint in one layer. Question: should I use something like tf.keras.constraints.NonNeg() or should I replace each weight $w$ on which I want to apply the constraint with $\exp w$ ("reparameterization") (since $\exp >0$)or is there no general rule?